# Missing semi colon despite semi-colon being there?

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors, compilation, syntax-error

I am attempting to compile somebody else's code to analyze it. As it's often the case, their code does not compile on my current setup, so I have been going around tweaking minor things (Only things like changing forward slashes to backslashes or adding library directories to include statements (e.g GL/)) I have not modified any logic nor have I deleted any include statements.

The process was going smoothly until I encountered this issued.

I have the following source file:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Material;

/// <summary> Manages all loaded materials and shader programs. </summary>
class MaterialStore {
public:
    static MaterialStore& getInstance();
    std::vector<Material*> materials;
    Material *findMaterialWithName(std::string name);
    Material *findMaterialWithProgramID(unsigned int programID);
    void AddNewMaterial(
        std::string name, const char * vertexPath = nullptr, const char * fragmentPath = nullptr,
        const char * geometryPath = nullptr, const char * tessEvalPath = nullptr, const char * tessCtrlPath = nullptr);
    ~MaterialStore();
private:
    MaterialStore();
    MaterialStore(MaterialStore const &) = delete;
    void operator=(MaterialStore const &) = delete;
};
```

Which is not compiling with error message:

[image]

I do no understand the problem. The semi colon is there (I have tried deleting and adding it). And I cannot find any syntax error.

Comment: Bit of a deceiving error message, but the issue is you've neglected to `#include <string>`

Comment: I have not neglected anything, whoever wrote the library did : P

Comment: They probably compiled with libc++, while you're likely compiling with libstdc++.

Comment: @miradulo i think if header `<vector>` doesn't including the definition of `string`, then `<xstring>` is needed